# Achieving Grid Layout of Buttons with Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to achieve a layout of buttons very similar to Apple's inbuilt Calculator app:
[image: Closeup of calc application]

I am using autolayout to position the buttons, and drawing a 0.5px border on each button, aiming for a 1px gap between buttons (like the calc app, closeup showing pixels above, from a retina device).

Border applied by :

```
    btn.layer.borderWidth=0.5f;
    btn.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```

and the layout is set up using Interface Builder.

[image: app screenshot]

It almost works; but there is some variability in the gap between buttons - for example the gap between the "1,2,3,thru" row and the "4,5,6,and" row is 2 pixels, but the gap between the "7,8,9" and "cl,0,@" rows is only one pixel.

Constraints are :

- Top black area has a fixed height
- All buttons same height
- In the numeric rows, numeric buttons are set to same width, THRU, AND, ALL OFF and ENTER buttons are set to same fixed width
- Top row of buttons pinned to bottom of black area, bottom row pinned to bottom of superview
  In IB the buttons are all positioned butting up against each other.

In interface builder and at runtime I don't see any autolayout errors; and a debugger dump of the autolayout info gives me:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]

*<UIWindow:0x10908a560> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   *<UILayoutContainerView:0x109136140>
|   |   *<UINavigationTransitionView:0x10908ef80>
|   |   |   *<UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x109138870>
|   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x1090e6d10>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x1090d5bb0>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090d27e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091c9190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090844c0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091c7990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x109088b60>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091c6190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090e2ce0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091c4990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090e4e50>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091c3190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090db730>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091c1990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x109068f50>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091c0190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x10906db80>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091be990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090d23a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091bd190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090c8520>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091bb990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090c9090>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091ba190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090c5680>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091b8990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090d7fa0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091b7190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090cc820>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091b5990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x10909dda0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091b4190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090c8090>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091b2990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090c8e30>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091b1190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090d5390>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091af990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x10d30d260>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091ae190>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x10909a6a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x1091ac990>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090cca40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x109161160>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x10d30ea90>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x109156460>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1090da9e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x109177ad0>
|   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x1090e6dd0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x1090ce080> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   <UINavigationBar:0x10907da60>
|   |   |   <_UINavigationBarBackground:0x109087240>
|   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropView:0x1090899f0>
|   |   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropEffectView:0x10908b110>
|   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x10908bbb0>
|   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x1090877a0>
|   |   |   <UINavigationItemView:0x10916bc30>
|   |   |   |   <UILabel:0x10917f810>
|   |   |   <UINavigationItemButtonView:0x1090ee060>
|   |   |   |   <UILabel:0x1090ee5d0>
|   |   |   <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView:0x109098c80>
```

Can anyone offer any hints on how to achieve a "pixel perfect" layout like this with Autolayout? Or should I be doing this programatically instead?

Comment: I suspect that there isn't the available extra 1 pixel based on your constraints. that's why you are getting the discrepancy ? what happens if you take 1 pixel off the height of the black view at the top ?

Comment: The top black view is constrained to >=100px high - I just tried it both as >=99 and =99 and =30, but the problem still remains the same.

Comment: You've got an ambiguous layout though ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any reported problems of ambiguous layout in interface builder; I do get the report above from the debugger, which indicates the UILayoutGuides as having "ambiguous layout", but I don't have anything referenced to the layout guides so not sure how to eliminate that

Comment: I think the UILayoutGuides eliminate the space that iOS 7 now uses under the nav bar. The Guides being to start the layout beneath it as a posed to under the status bar directly. I know a UILayout guru. I will forward this to him, maybe he can help.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're giving retina or non-retina dimensions. If you're giving retina, I think you need to say "pt" instead of "px" in the first sentence for your description to add up. Just want to make sure I'm reading the question right.

Comment: I am actually hoping for a 1 pixel gap - I am trying to match the look of the inbuilt calculator app, which I added a screenshot of from a retina device to the question

Comment: Constraints are always in points. You don't need to think about pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to set horizontal/vertical spaces between views equal to 0.5. The color of parent view acts as border color. It looks ugly in IB, it cannot layout views properly but resulting layout on device looks perfect.

In interface builder:

[image: in interface builder]

On simulator:

[image: on device]

Constraints are a bit tricky. For **each row**:

- set height for the 1st button
- set equal height for all buttons
- set equal width for all buttons (a bit different for rows with orange buttons)
- align top edges of all buttons
- align bottom edges of all buttons
- set leading and trailing spaces between all buttons (including spaces to superview) to 0.5
- set top space (to previous row) of 1st button to 0.5

You can apply constraints to multiple items at once. In order to apply leading/trailing spaces between buttons, place them without intersection in desired order before applying.

Answer (score 4):

Layer borders are drawn inside the views bounds, so you aren't going to see a "gap" between the buttons, but the effect of two borders abutting each other. This isn't going to work in the non-retina simulator or devices, since it can't draw a half-pixel, and Autolayout doesn't align views on half-pixels.

For a layout like the one above I'd be giving a fixed height to the buttons (or to one button, and making the others equal it) and letting the black view take up the remaining space. It's always best to have at least one (ideally, exactly one) variable element in a full-screen layout basically to cover rounding errors.

It sounds at the moment like you have one fixed element (the black view) and the buttons are basically "take the remaining height and divide it between yourselves", which will only work if the remaining height divides perfectly.

Comment: The reason I was hoping to have the views divide the remaining space was because when rotating to landscape orientation, I'd like the black area to have a minimum size, and the buttons to fill up the remaining space - without that the buttons end up being either too large in landscape or too small in portrait - again like the calculator app.

Comment: Is this for iPhone? iPad? Which screen sizes are you supporting?

Comment: iPhone, building for iOS7 so supporting iPhone 4, 4S, 5 retina displays.